# Putting everything from arraylist to one line?

Tags: python, arraylist, jython

thanks for reading my question, I hope I'll find answer. At the moment, I'm trying to figure out how to make this. I'm making an bukkit plugin in python/jython, and while making new in-game command I define it and make args. Like this:

```
@hook.command("blabla", usage="/blabla <message>", desc="Sends message to blabla chat.",      aliases=["bl", "bla", "b"])        
def blabla(sender, command, args):
    #do something
```

Arguemnts are acutally "message", so everything that comes after "/blabla" are arguments, named like args[0] for first, args[1] for second and so on...

If I for example use this message, when I print args out I get this:

```
Everything okay? :)    

array(java.lang.String, [u'Everything', u'okay?', u':)'])
```

What I don't know is, how can I take all arguments (have on mind that I don't know number of them, so I can't use args[0,1,2,3]) and make them as one "message", so I can call it later. Example code I want to achieve:

```
@hook.command("blabla", usage="/blabla <message>", desc="Sends message to blabla chat.",      aliases=["bl", "bla", "b"])        
def blabla(sender, command, args):
    message = all arguments #Summed up, how to do this?
    print "Stackoverflow_user_example sent this message:", message
```

Thank you for your time, I appreciate it.

btw. I use jython/python.

Comment: Perhaps `' '.join(args)`?

Comment: @DanD. What? I'm sorry but I'm not sure I understand you, where should I use that?

Comment: `message = ' '.join(args)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> args = [u'Everything', u'okay?', u':)']
>>> message = ' '.join(args)
>>> print message
Everything okay? :)
```

Comment: That works ! :) Thank you very much, I'll accept your answer as soon as I get allowed to, I need to wait 3 more minutes..